# mysql count 2 field

Tags: mysql, count, sum

I have 1 table and I want to count/sum 2 column which has date greater than the other

as example

```
id | comment | articleid | dateadd    | dateupdate |
1     bla      1           2011-01-01   2011-01-01
2     hello    1           2011-01-01   2011-01-01
3     whooaa   1           2011-01-01   2011-01-02
```

The query suppose to return "3 comment and 1 updated".

Thanks in advance

Comment: please format your code using code button in toolbar

Comment: `COUNT(*) as comment, SUM(IF(dateupdate>dateadd,1,0)) as updated`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be grouping the records by `articleID` and filtering the aggregated result using `HAVING`.

```
SELECT  articleID,
        COUNT(*) totalCooments,
        SUM(dateUpdate > dateadd) totalUpdated
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY articleID
HAVING  SUM(dateUpdate > dateadd) > 0
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/681f0/1)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*when nothing is updated*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f378b/1)